# How to code for reading pdf file in android?

Tags: android

How to code for reading a pdf file in android? i want to build an app like RepliGo reader. So, Please enlighten me to read pdf by using android sdk or ndk.

Answer (score 0):

1. Learn Java
2. Download the SDK with Eclipse
3. Work through some tutorials to get a flavour of programming on Android
4. Have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.ehow.com/how_5144603_read-pdf-files-using-java.html) on reading pdfs in Java
5. Write your app!